# Handlebars templates using ampersand and caret

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

We found some old Handlebars templates which are working fine, but include some odd usage of Handlebars.

The two strange ones are

```
{{^is_question}}{{/is_question}}
```

and

```
{{& answer}}
```

Neither of those are listed in the Handlerbars docs and there are no helpers defined.

Anyone know what they do?

The ^is_question appears to be used interchangeably with {{#if is_question}}. Maybe it is some deprecated shorthand notation?

The template is compiled the same way we compile other templates:

```
template = Handlebars.compile(ItemTemplate)
```

Our handlebars version is:

```
Handlebars.VERSION = "1.0.0-rc.3";
```

Comment: I don't recognize this either.  Is it possible someone had a custom task to translate this notation into true handlebars?

Comment: use of ^ seems to be taken from Mustache templating

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've used [^](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/cf343a19495f92aba19111441f974588c835e735/spec/parser.js#L148) relatively recently, but I had to look up [&](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/f30b3ea3293ad28bad8167e40b8372c48cb2419e/spec/basic.js#L83):

```
{{^ question}} X {{/question}} => inverse selection, i.e. if (! question ) X;
{{& answer}} => unescaped, typically: {{{answer}}}
```