# What does {{^ mean in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template that contains:

```
{{^is mymodel.someproperty}}
```

I don't understand what the significance of the caret symbol is.  I've searched around, the only place I'm seeing it is on [Handlebars Expressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html)

It's used like so:

```html
{{#each nav}}
  <a href="{{url}}">
    {{#if test}}
      {{title}}
    {{^}}
      Empty
    {{/if}}
  </a>
{{~/each}}
```

What does "{{^" mean in handlebars?  It sort of looks like a .NOT. or .ELSE. or something like that.

-Eric

Answer (score 6):

The reason it's not in the handlebars doc is because it's a mustache construct called an Inverted Section.

See: https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Inverted-Sections

```
{{#repo}}
  <b>{{name}}</b>
{{/repo}}
{{^repo}}
  No repos :(
{{/repo}}
```

Answer (score 2):

... disabling **inverse operations** such as {{^foo}}{{/foo}} unless fields are explicitly included in the source object._

http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html

http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html

Comment: From reading the documentation, it sounds like {{^ isn't strict mode, but that strict mode disables inverse operations such as {{^foo}}{{/foo}}.  I think like {{^ and {{/ are both some kind of inverse operation.

Comment: I'm not clear on the difference between {{^ and {{/.  {{/ iis used to close a handlebars block and {{/ is apparently .NOT., although I can't find any documentation for it.  I can't imaging that strict mode would prevent you from closing a block.

Comment: I think / is close and ^ is not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026519/handlebars-templates-using-ampersand-and-caret