# In HandlebarsJS, what is {{^}}?

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I ran across a carrot-like symbol `{{^}}`, in this template snippet:

```
<p class="{{ type }}">
  {{#is_auth}}
  {{^is_submitted}}
  <label for="place-{{ name }}">{{ prompt }} {{# optional }}<small>({{#_}}optional{{/_}})</small>{{/ optional }}</label>
  {{/is_submitted}}
  {{^}}
  <label for="place-{{ name }}">{{ prompt }} {{# optional }}<small>({{#_}}optional{{/_}})</small>{{/ optional }}</label>
  {{/is_auth}}
```

What does the `{{^}}` mean? Since this is a symbol, it is hard to search, and I could not find it in the [handlebarsjs tutorial](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

From the looks of it, it appears to be some kind of "else" operator, but I am not sure.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244435/what-does-mean-in-handlebars?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a short-hand inverse operator. It evaluates the section only if the variable is false. In the above example:

```
{{^is_submitted}}
```

This is an "else-if" expression, displaying the section if is_submitted is false.

```
{{^}}
```

An "else" operator.

The [HandleBarJS website](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) has (little bit) more information.